# Not able to parse JsonPath in restassured

Tags: groovy, rest-assured-jsonpath

Using Restassured 3.0.1

I have a Json ::

```
json = {
"prices": {
    "Test": {
        "PriceMap": {
            "30": "295"
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(json);
jsonPath.get("prices.Test.PriceMap.*")
```

getting error :

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: * @ line 1, column 48.
   otObject.prices.Test.PriceMap.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getMap call to get the object as a map -- **jsonPath.getMap("prices.Test.PriceMap")**

```
System.out.println(jsonPath.getMap("prices.Test.PriceMap").keySet());
//Output : [30]
System.out.println(jsonPath.getMap("prices.Test.PriceMap").values());
//[295]        
System.out.println(jsonPath.getMap("prices.Test.PriceMap").get("30"));
//295
```